# PHP - How set date and time stamp in a Custom Field during import

Tags: php, wpallimport

I’d like to set the current date and time to a Custom Field `'Latest update'` when running an import via cron on a regular basis, so I can see when the last update successfully ran. 
Note: I realize WP All Import has logs but I want to show the custom `'Latest update'` field in the product admin listing and check if the pricing was updated whilst doing other product updates dependent on the latest import.

I tried many PHP functions but none work so far. 
Could you let me know what I should do instead?
Some variations I tried and the error I get:

```
[print date(“d-m-Y H:i”)] : ERROR: Call to undefined function “print date”
[echo date(“d-m-Y H:i”)] : ERROR: Call to undefined function “echo date”
[print date (“d-m-Y H:i”)] : ERROR: Unexpected token OPEN, statement was expected.
[print date = date(“d-m-Y H:i”)] : ERROR: Unexpected token OPEN, statement was expected.
[date = date(“d-m-Y H:i”)] : ERROR: Unexpected token OPEN, statement was expected.
[date = date(”d-m-Y H:i”)] : ERROR: Unexpected symbol ‘
```

– When using shortcodes/PHP functions, use double quotes “, not single quotes ‘

I read that I should use ” instead of single quote ‘ (as is in one of the errors) so that one is clear. But what else am I doing wrong?

Does anyone have a solution?

I don't mind whether the Custom Field 'Latest update' is a text field or a data field (I tried both with all PHP function options above) let me know if relevant for a solution offered how I should format the custom field.

I'd really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I got from WPAllImport:

```
[date("d-m-Y H:i")]
```

It works. Thought I'd share it in case it helps others.